# Can I get Stallman on Meta?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

I edited a CW post that was [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads), does that count? It doesn't appear to have done.

[The post in question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads)

[My edit (alt-text)](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/8064/revisions)

Comment: Why don't you just edit the sandbox?

Comment: @Antony That is extremely devious. 10/10.

Comment: And you get the "A Link to the Past" hat for free.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Is this legit?

Comment: I got them that way. Why shouldn't I test with some markup in the sandbox just because I could get some hats for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to get the Stallman hat by editing a community wiki post on meta.SO.

I [edited the Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) and got the hat in question.

Comment: Stackoverflow Meta is special.

Comment: Snowflake special! I am going to have to go test this on site specific metas, now, aren't I? :P

Comment: @fredley was talking about site-meta though

Comment: The question wasn't tagged per-site-meta, I'm not a mind reader!

Answer (score 1):

Actions on child metas only count for hats that explicitly mention something like "on meta". Meta.SO is special, because it's not a "real" child meta (yet), so actions here count both for main-site hats (which you'll earn here) and "on meta" hats (which you'll earn on Stack Overflow). Peanut Gallery cannot be earned on Meta.SO (that's why it says "non-meta"), and of course "on meta" hats can't be earned here either, nor on Stack Apps, because neither has a meta.